# How to use launchd to ensure an application is running?

Tags: macos, launchd

I use Quicksilver, which is a nifty program that really speeds up my work. I've set it to launch when I log in.

However, since Snow Leopard, it's become a bit less stable, and once in a while, it crashes. And obviously, it won't restart by itself.

I'm pretty sure I can use `launchd` to ensure it's always running when I'm logged in. Is there a good guide/example of how to make sure a process restarts when it's killed/terminated/crashed with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for `launchd quicksilver` I got this [website](http://www.zzamboni.org/brt/2008/01/28/using-launchd-to-immortalize-quicksilver-howto/index.html) ... which looks right.

Here's the gist of it in case that page ever goes away:

- In the QS preferences, disable “start at login”
- Create a new LaunchAgent in my account by storing the following file as ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.quicksilver.plist (actually I used Lingon to create the file – very handy utility!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.quicksilver</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Applications/Quicksilver.app/Contents/MacOS/Quicksilver</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

See `man launchd.plist` for more information about the keys you can put into a launchd plist file to control when and how launchd launches or re-launches processes.

See also: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).

Comment: Yup, looks right. I'll check it at home later.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, as I don't have a mac, but I've been told it has bash as default shell these days. You could possibly get this going with a bash-script that you execute on logon by any means.

What it basically does is execute the given command repeatedly until it returns zero, which means it closed normally.

```
#!/bin/bash

RETVAL=1
until [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; do
    # change this to whatever is used to launch quicksilver
    /Applications/Quicksilver.app/Quicksilver

    RETVAL=$?
done
```

Edit: To clarify, put that in an empty text-file (optionally with an .sh-extension) and give it execute permissions (`chmod +x filename`) and it should work.

Comment: That's indeed a solution, though I'd prefer `launchd` since it's apparently its purpose. (Also, just so you know, executables are located inside the `Contents/MacOS` folder of an application bundle.) Thanks though, I didn't think about a shell script for the job before you mentioned it.

Comment: You clearly know nothing about Macs and should refrain from posting anything on the subject.

Comment: @Hasaan: While I mostly agree with your pointing out my lack of knowledge of macs, I do not see where my possible solution failed. It does what the OP wanted, just not in the way he wanted. For your enjoyment I will refrain from posting possible solutions to future problems, unless the solution in question is what the OP wanted, to the letter.

Comment: @Hasaan Chop: You clearly know nothing about what I consider good or not and should refrain from posting anything on the subject.